# JSONException:<String>cannot be converted to JSONObject with helps of JSON Array

Tags: java, android, hashmap, json

> $ **Error**:: JSONException:json string cannot be converted to
>   JSONObject with helps of JSON Array

**This is Import libraries**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

**activity_main.xml file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp" >
</ListView>
```

**Internet Permission is Here**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

`error` Please give me Answer How to get Multiple Values Using this Code and show into my ListView

**This Is my MainActivity.java class file.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private String jsonResult;
    private String url = "YOUR_PHP_FILE_URL";
    private ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        accessWebService();
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
     {
          // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
          return true;
     }

     // Async Task to access the web
     @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
     {
         @Override
         protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
         {
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
             try
             {
                 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                 jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
             }
             catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             } 
             catch (IOException e)
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             return null;
         }

         private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) 
         {
             String rLine = "";
             StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
             BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

             try 
             {
                 while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null)
                 {
                     answer.append(rLine);
                     Log.d(answer.toString(), "String Builder Class in IF Loop");
                 }
             }
             catch (IOException e)
             {
                 // e.printStackTrace();
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 Log.d(answer.toString(), "String Builder Class in Else Part");
             }
             return answer;
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(String result)
         {
             ListDrwaer();
         }
     }// end async task

     public void accessWebService()
     {
         JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
          // passes values for the urls string array
          task.execute(new String[] { url });
     }

     // build hash set for list view
     public <jsonResult> void ListDrwaer() 
     {
         ArrayList<Map<String,String>> userList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
         Log.d(userList.toString(), "Starting JSONObject");

         try 
         {             
             Log.d("Starting Try Block", "Before JSONObject");

             JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
             JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("user_info");

             Log.d(jsonMainNode.toString(), "Starting JSONObject");

             for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) 
             {
                 JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                 String id = jsonChildNode.optString("Id:");
                 String name = jsonChildNode.optString("Name:");
                 String email = jsonChildNode.optString("Email:");
                 String phone = jsonChildNode.optString("Phone:");
                 String password = jsonChildNode.optString("Password");
                 String outPut = id + "-" + name+ "-" + email+ "-" + phone+ "-" + password;
                 userList.add(createEmployee("user_info", outPut));
                 Log.d(jsonChildNode.toString(), "Starting JSONObject inside For Loop");
             }
         } 
         catch (JSONException e)
         {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Log.e("log_tag", "Failed data was:\n" + jsonResult);
         }

         SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, userList,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,new String[] { "user_info" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
         listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
     }

     private HashMap<String, String> createEmployee(String name, String number) 
     {
      HashMap<String, String> employeeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
      employeeNameNo.put(name, number);
      return employeeNameNo;
     }
}
```

Comment: Probably trying to convert JSONArray to JSONObject. show `jsonResult ` String also with Question

Comment: Could you post the complete error log ?. As @ρяσѕρєяK noted, You might be trying to convert JSONArray to JSONObject or may be some other format of text, such as html. I had the same problem, where i tried to parse some `404` html message to `JSONObject`. :)

Comment: Add your LogCat result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok the error you are getting is very generic, error itself tells what you are doing wrong

> $ Error:: JSONException:json string cannot be converted to JSONObject with helps of JSON Array,

I believe you have string in the JSON data, `"dummy data"` as it is in double quotes which you are trying to read as a `JSONObject`.
It is not a `JSONObject`  but a `String` primitive type,

while parsing `JSON` you need to pay attention to what is a `Object`, `Array` and `primitive-type`

```
JSONObject
```

will always be enclosed in `{ }` so this represents that data inside a parentheses is a JSONObject, 
Example===>

```
JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
```

or

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject("JSON DATA");


JSONArray
```

will always be enclosed in `[ ]` so this represents that data inside a square bracket is a JSONArray,
Example==> `json.getJSONArray("name of jsonArray");

```
Primitive-type
```

`Boolean` would like this

```
"isSelected":true
or
"isSelected":false
```

`Integer` would like this

```
"someInt":12
```

`String` would like this

```
"someString":"String value"
```

as you can see where your problem is, you need to distinguish between `JSON` String from `JSON Object`

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line because you convert Json String to Json Object

```
 JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
```